# Convert date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-update, converters

Im trying to update a column in SQL so i tried using this:

```
       update [BaseHistorica_]
       set Cierre=CONVERT(datetime2,cierre,103)
```

But appears the following error message:

```
       Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
       Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Then i tried this query, and the result was that i was expecting

```
  SELECT top 1000 [ID]
  ,convert(datetime2,[Cierre],103) as cierre
  ,[Seg1]
  ,[Mora1]
  ,[Saldo_T]
  ,[Saldo_FD]
  ,[Seg2]
  ,[Mora2]
   FROM [TARSHOP].[dbo].[BaseHistorica_]
```

and finally i tried this query to create a table that i want, with the same error message.

```
  SELECT top 1000 [ID]
  ,convert(datetime2,[Cierre],103) as cierre
  ,[Seg1]
  ,[Mora1]
  ,[Saldo_T]
  ,[Saldo_FD]
  ,[Seg2]
  ,[Mora2]
  into [BaseHistoricaF]
  FROM [T].[dbo].[BaseHistorica_]
```

Why can be happen? how can i do to update this column or create a table with this column.

Comment: `SELECT ID, Cierre FROM dbo.[TARSHOP].[dbo].[BaseHistorica_] WHERE ISDATE(Cierre) = 0;` - this is why you don't use string columns to store date/time data.

Comment: Also you are using top but have no order by. That is like saying, "give me any 1000 rows, I don't care which ones".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells us that attempting to convert into datetime2 fails "from character string"; hence [Cierre] appears to be a string already.

1. learn what the actual data type of [Cierre] is first (probably varchar or nvarchar)
2. then learn what format the `stored` values conform to,  possibly (if you are lucky) YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD
3. do NOT set them to a different format, & absolutely NOT 103 (DD/MM/YYYY)
4. Use convert(varchar,[Cierre],103) for output only!

If storing date/time information as strings then

- you simply MUST understand how the values are stored, and
- you are denied simple access to many date/time functions

Put simply storing date/time information as strings is bad and will make life in your SQL world more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is column Cierre is a string format, such as varchar or nvarcher. When updating BaseHistorica_ you're trying to convert cierre to datetime2 and store it in column Cierre, which is a string. You'll have to figure out the format of the strings in Cierre and conform to that standard.

There's a problem with saving your dates as varchars though.  One is that anyone else can input a date in a different format.  For instance, '01/08/2014' and you input the date as '01-08-2014'. They're totally different values because they're strings, not dates.  The best thing to do is to have your date columns formatted as dates, in your case datetime2, and then format the dates when you're querying the data. When your values are dates then you can use various SQL functions such as date ranges (BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '01/01/2013') and DATEDIFF.   So the rule of thumb is to store as date and only format the output.

Comment: the datetime datatype is NOT stored in any human readable format - that is completely wrong - they are stored as 2 integers. It is only as input or as output do we "see" the human readable date styles.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the problem probably occurred because you are trying to store the `DATETIME` in a column that will only hold `STRING` (or `CHAR`) value.

What happen is, that `Cierre` column is `STRING` datatype. When you do `CONVERT(datetime2,cierre,103)`, it has converted the value into `DATETIME`, and then you want to store them back to the column that only holds `STRING`

I think what you need to do is, you have to create a temp column that is `DATETIME` datatype, then convert and copy that column to this new temp column.